# String tokenization c troubles

Tags: c, string, tokenize

I have this code that takes a file "schedule.txt" and let's the user enter a class in and it displays the time the class is at, unfortunately I am having difficulties with the tokenizing...

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    // Declare variables
    FILE *inp = NULL;
    char str[200];
    char class[7][20];
    double times[15];
    double times2[15];
    int i;
    const char delim[] = " 0123456789:";

    // Open the file, quit if it fails...
    inp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(inp == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file: %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }

    // Read the file and tokenize it for names of classes and times
    i = 0;
    while(fgets(str, 200, inp) != NULL){
        str[strlen(str)-1] = '\0';

        char *classToken = strtok(str, "0123456789");
        strcpy(class[i], classToken);

        char *timeToken = strtok(NULL, " ");
        times[i] = atof(timeToken);

        i++;
    }

    for(i = 2; i < 6; i++){
        printf("%f\n", times[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I wish to tokenize the file into two different arrays, one containing the string of the class, and the other being the times without the ":", but when I have the delimiter as the numbers it doesn't let me use the first number of the time, but when the delimiter is " " the string array contains the times as well, how could I do this? **The file looks like this**:

```
 Class Schedule
 Class          Time
 Physics            15:30
 Calculus       9:00
 Biology            14:30
 Chemistry      11:30
```

Comment: An unrelated note: If the line you attempt to read with `fgets` is 199 characters of more, then the newline will not be appended to the buffer.

Comment: Another unrelated note: You should probably read about *structures*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems you have: The first is that `strtok` modifies the string, and replaces the found token separator with the string terminator.

So if your input string looks like `"Physics 15:30"` the after the first call to `strtok` it will have been modified to look like `"Physics \05:30"`.

The solution to this is to use *space* (or tab, or both) as the token separator, and then skip spaces when getting the next token.

The second problem is that you use `atof` to get the time. A time is not a floating-point value, especially no current numbering system uses `:` to separate the integer and fraction part. Not to mention that `15:30` as a floating point number would be `15.30` which is not the same as `15.50` (which in turn is not the same as the time `15:50`).

An easy solution for both problems is to use [`sscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) instead to parse the line into two *strings*.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that the delimiter is inappropriate.
Specifically, It will tokenize as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct schedule {
    char className[20];
    int  time;//minute
}Schedule;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *inp;
    char line[200];
    char title[32];
    char fieldName[2][20];
    Schedule schedule[7];
    int i;

    if(argc != 2){
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage : %s filename\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    inp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(inp == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file: %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }

    fgets(title, sizeof title, inp);
    fgets(line, sizeof line, inp);
    char *token;
    token = strtok(line, " \t\n");
    strcpy(fieldName[0], token);
    token = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
    strcpy(fieldName[1], token);

    i = 0;
    while(i < 7 && fgets(line, sizeof line, inp)){
        token = strtok(line, " \t\n");//maybe "\t\n"
        strcpy(schedule[i].className, token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
        schedule[i].time = atoi(token)*60 + atoi(strchr(token, ':')+1);//"hh:mm" : hh * 60 + mm 
        i++;
    }
    int n = i;

    printf("%s", title);
    printf("%-20s%s\n", fieldName[0], fieldName[1]);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("%-20s%02d:%02d\n", schedule[i].className, schedule[i].time/60, schedule[i].time%60);
    }

    return 0;
}
```